# How to set no nextfocus in android widget?

Tags: android

We can use "nextFocusUp" "nextFocusDwon" "nextFocusLeft" "nextFocusRight" to control next focus.
But how to  set no next focus?
I can not find some way to do it.
Dose anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it you want to prevent the focus moving away from an item. I recently had the same issue and managed to solve it by setting all the "nextFocus..." values to the same id as the control:

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/list"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/list"
        ...etc
        ...... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

First add linear layout at the begining of your layout like this

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/my_layout" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" ...>
```

And then to remove focus from your button/editText do this:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
myLayout.requestFocus();
```